# additional c++ sources generating errors in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

I have some source written by one of my colleagues in C++. They are stuffs for numerical analysis. I wish them to be included in my Objective-C/Cocoa project. Building seems not to be accomplished... with a kinda error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_calcThomas", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm a novice in Xcode or clang. I have a lot of Xcode documentation, and can't find a related one to solve my own. How to achieve my project to work with c++?

Additionally,

- The original c++ sources are pure c++ code composed of c++ sources and headers.
- They are compiled perfectly in case the project is created only with c++ code template, not with Foundation template.

Thanks hopefully.

Comment: ARe you compiling them as 64 bit in your project?

Comment: Check for name mangling - are you exporting `calcThomas` with C linkage?

Comment: @GWW: It is compiled neither in 32/64 bit nor in 64 bit.

Comment: @C. Norum: One more question. All of c++ functions have to be exported with C linkage? or the only c++ functions which are called directly from main objective-c code could have C linkage?